# jQuery plugin for showing large image on hover with responsivity

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I´m looking for a jQuery plugin that offers responsive display of large image in popup on hovering thumbnail.
I have found this plugin, which comes pretty close to what I want but it is not responsive and I need the popup to be placed on right side or left side depending on the position of the thumbnail:
http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/02/

What I´m looking for is actually exactly as it is on Themefore.net when you hover thumbnails on this page:
http://themeforest.net/category/ecommerce/magento/shopping

Does anyone know a jQuery plugin with similar popup features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get a similar image hover display as seen on Envato I made this basic CSS and JS:

HTML markup:

```
<div class="container">
<img class="thumbnail" src="https://thumb-tf.s3.envato.com/files/141892492/icon.png" title="">    
<img class="hidden-large" src="https://preview-tf.s3.envato.com/files/141892504/screenshot.__large_preview.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img.hidden-large {
  display: none;
  z-index:1000;  
}
img.thumbnail {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS:

```
jQuery('img.thumbnail').hover( function() {
var pos = jQuery(this).position();
var outerwidth = jQuery(".container").width();
var width = jQuery(this).outerWidth();

var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://preview-tf.s3.envato.com/files/141892504/screenshot.__large_preview.jpg';    
var largeimgwidth = img.width;

if((outerwidth-width) > largeimgwidth) {
jQuery("img.hidden-large").css({
position: "absolute",
top: pos.top + "px",
left: (pos.left + width) + "px"
}).toggle();       
}
});
```

JSfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/br7d9js2/

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is create a css class / element in dom to show your pop up.

Then use jquery http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/
"mouse enter" / "mouse leave" to show hide your pop ups.

Comment: I made my own custom solution using simple CSS and a little bit of JS.
See the answer below